# How to directly email my resume to big companies?

Tags: resume, job-search, applications

How do I find email addresses of people / HR departments in big US companies such as Amazon, Ebay, Home Depot, CNN, Verizon, AT&T, to email them my resume directly? Do lists of such email addresses appear online somewhere?

Comment: Go through their official application process, that's literally what it's there for. It's naive to think you can find out how to bypass that by just asking a question here.

Comment: You can't, because they'd be spammed down with poor applicants. They have a process for a reason, and that is weeding out the 80% irrelevant applicants before they have to process anything.

Comment: A reference(be it a favorable one if they know your work or just one for the sake of courtesy) is extremely more efficient than any generic  email you re going to cold send them.

Comment: @cbll or poor applicants are those who are willing to waste their time on re-entering the content of their resume into 900 text fields, knowing that there is quite a small chance that they get the job or even actually want it after all. It really shows nothing but servility, which is in fact valuable for company owners.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I rarely see those cases nowadays. Maybe it's normal in the US, but in Europe, companies have moved on from the "please enter every detail of your CV into these input fields.." :) Normally it's just submitting a CV, cover letter, and some contact details.

Comment: @cbll The "upload your resume" is what I see a lot of companies do, esp the not too big ones. Like here in SO the job search section, most companies do it the easy way, but some redirect me to their external form, sometimes they would even want me to create an account. Ctrl+w.

Answer (score 9):

I advise against direct email. At best, you're frustrating folks who might have hired you if you'd gone through proper channels. At worst, you're spamming them and they're annoyed to see your email.

I recommend using the jobs portals of big companies to apply to them. As someone who works for a larger company, I can tell you that everyone must go through the same channel to apply. Even if you were to get your resume through, you'd probably still need to go back and apply through proper channels later.

Comment: What do you mean by job portals of big companies? Many of these companies publish jobs on their websites, but the application process is annoying, essentially rewrite my resume. It's not like "upload your resume". So I give up. But often "consulting companies" collect these job ads and access me (with the hope to pocket X% of my salary for doing almost nothing), and I know that they do not submit my resume through the end client website, but by talking directly to their HR. Also, often these "consulting companies" are just one guy spamming from his studio apt, why can't I talk to HR like that?

Comment: "but the application process is annoying, essentially rewrite my resume." Big companies see a LOT of resumes. If you actually want the job you darn well better be tailoring your resume to the specifics of the position.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant "the specifics of the position"? I beg to differ. Anyway I am familiar with your school of thought but it should be clear from my question that after much deliberation I have personally concluded that the juice is not worth the squeeze. So a good answer to my question would focus on what I actually asked.

Comment: @rapt If the effort of applying through their job portals is not worth your time, then your CV is not worth the company's time either. Why would they hire someone who ignored their systems and just did what they wanted their own way?

Comment: @Draken because I figured that companies, esp big ones are not well coordinated, to put it mildly; developers/interviewers do not set the idiotic application process for a corp, and they may sometimes be open-minded, and focus on essence rather than bureaucracy. Obviously this is not the case with the ones in this thread, but sometimes (not too often, but sometimes), people just enjoy good ideas, even if they don't come in a Microsoft doc with the right font.

Answer (score 2):

> Do lists of such email addresses appear online somewhere?

Yes. These are called sales leads.

Find a company that sells such lists and purchase one. Something like https://www.google.com/search?q=sales+leads will help.

(Note: I think what you are intending is a waste of time. But that wasn't your question.)

Comment: I was more thinking of email addresses such as jobs@company.com or recruit@company.com, some companies have such things.

Comment: If they do, you'll likely find it on their homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Find someone that works at their company on GitHub. Find a repository that they are active in or better yet one that they run.

Look at the active issues and send a good Pull Request following all best practices.

Mention that you are currently looking for work.

Comment: Very good out of the box thinking here!

Comment: It's a good idea almost, although it would miserably defeat the purpose of saving my own time on doing things with very low rates of success. It's been more useful for me to focus on my projects and let others do what you suggest; I have got some offers in the past from people who use these projects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in many of these companies HR is not a central location. So that when location X in the company needs to find a new employee they post via the jobs portal, but the decisions are made locally. In some of these companies they do have a way to tap into any resume that is in their database, but there is no guarantee that they will use this option.

If you email a person in HR you will be asking them to enter your resume and data into their system. They have zero incentive for doing so. Unless they need your resume for a position they are filling now there is no upside for them. You also risk that they will do a poor job, thus further limiting your chances.

If you do want to do this then go to each company and search the jobs/careers portion of their site for contact information.

Hey if there is a real need for this maybe you can start to assemble the list, publish it to the web, and keep it up-to-date.